# Cannot create bean. Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field

Tags: spring-boot

I have added `@ComponentScan`, `@EntityScan` in the main class still the same error, I'm new to this and getting this error from few days. Please help to solve this.

Stacktrace:

```
 Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepo' : nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in org.simplilearn.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List org.simplilearn.repository.UserRepository.joinUserProductTable(); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List org.simplilearn.repository.UserRepository.joinUserProductTable()!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List org.simplilearn.repository.UserRepository.joinUserProductTable()!
```

MainClass
[image: MainClass]

Repository:

[image]

User Service:
[image]

User Entity:
[image]

Comment: first thing first: paste raw code instead of screenshots

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace (this one is unreadable) and post actual code instead of links to images of screenshots.